# Cloudinary URL not connecting to Spring Boot entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, cloudinary

I'm trying to parse the url of a multipart file out using cloudinary. For some reason though, I can't figure out why the cloudinary url isn't connecting to my spring boot entity connected to PostgresSQL. Specifically the image column. I have it down to four areas that could be affecting it, my Cloudinary config, my employee service class, my form controller, and my index file.

Here is the employee model:

```
package com.employee.employee.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employees {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String companyName;

    @Column
    private String role;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @Column
    private String image;


    public Employees(){
        
    }

    // public Employees(String companyName, String role, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String image) {
    //     this.companyName = companyName;
    //     this.role = role;
    //     this.firstName = firstName;
    //     this.lastName = lastName;
    //     this.age = age;
    //     this.image = image;
    // }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    
     public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Employee Form</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Employee Form</h1>
        <form id="employee-form" action="#" th:action="@{/employee}" th:object="${employees}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}"name="firstName">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" name="lastName">
            <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="companyName" th:field="*{companyName}" name="companyName">
            <label for="companyRoleName">Company Role</label>
            <input type="text" id="companyRoleName" th:field="*{role}" name="role">
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="text" id="age" th:field="*{age}" name="age">
            <input id="uploadImage" name="image" type="file" class="imageUpload" value="Upload Image">
            <input id="submitted" class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <button id="resultID" class="resultButton"><a href="/result">Get Card Result!</a></button>
        </form>
        
        <script src="submit-script.js"></script>
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

CloudinaryConfig.java:

```
package com.employee.employee.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


import com.cloudinary.*;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;


@Configuration
public class CloudinaryConfig {
    

@Bean
public Cloudinary cloudinary(){
    Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(dotenv.get("CLOUDINARY_URL"));
    cloudinary.config.secure = true;
    return cloudinary;
}
   
}
```

EmployeeService.java:

```
package com.employee.employee.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;
import com.employee.employee.models.Employees;
import com.employee.employee.repo.EmployeeRepo;



@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

    @Autowired
    Cloudinary cloudinary;


    public List<Employees> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeRepo.findAll();
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employees employee){

        employeeRepo.save(employee);
       
    }

  
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        try{
        String res = cloudinary.uploader()
                .upload(multipartFile.getBytes(), Map.of("public_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
                .get("url")
                .toString();

        System.out.println(res);

        return res;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return null;
    }


}
```

FormController.java:

```
package com.employee.employee.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.employee.employee.EmployeeAddException;
import com.employee.employee.models.Employees;
import com.employee.employee.service.EmployeeService;


@Controller
public class FormController {

    @Autowired 
    EmployeeService employeeService;

  
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employees", new Employees());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/result")
    public String getResult(){
      return "result";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/employee-result")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employees> employeeResult(){
     return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

    
    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public String employeeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Employees employee,
    @RequestParam("image")MultipartFile multipartFile, Model model) throws IOException{
      try{
      if(employee.getCompanyName().isBlank() || employee.getFirstName().isBlank() || employee.getLastName().isBlank()
      || employee.getRole().isBlank() || employee.getAge() == 0){
        
        throw new EmployeeAddException("Error: Employee can not be added, null value");
      }
    } catch (EmployeeAddException e){
      model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
      return "error";

    }
  
      String image = employeeService.uploadFile(multipartFile);
      employee.setImage(image);
      employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
      model.addAttribute("image", image);
      return "redirect:/";
    }

    
}
```

What I expected to happen was the image url to be passed to the PostgresSQL database. As well as the image be passed to the result page. The result page has an on-load script to show the images and the information after clicking the "Get Card Result" button on the index page.

result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Employee Cards</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="container">
        
    </main>
    <script src="on-load-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

on-load-script.js:

```
function getResult(){
    fetch("/employee-result")
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(employee => {
       const employeeList = document.getElementById("container");
       employee.forEach(employees => {

            //Elememts
            const employeeCard = document.createElement("div");
            const employeeCompany = document.createElement("p");
            const employeeName = document.createElement("p");
            const employeeRole = document.createElement("p");
            const employeeAge = document.createElement("p");
         
            const employeeImg = document.createElement("img");

           


            //Classes
            employeeCard.classList.add("cardContainer");
            employeeName.classList.add("bigFont");
       
            
         

            //Employee Info
            employeeCompany.innerHTML = employees.companyName;
            employeeName.innerHTML = employees.firstName + " " + employees.lastName;
            employeeRole.innerHTML = employees.role;
            employeeAge.innerHTML = "Age: " + employees.age;
            employeeImg.src = employees.image;
            employeeImg.alt = "Employee Image";
            
            //Employee Card append
            employeeCard.append(employeeName, employeeCompany, employeeRole, employeeAge, employeeImg);
            employeeList.appendChild(employeeCard);
       });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", getResult);
```

The error I get after clicking the "Get Card Results" button:

`submit-script.js:11     POST http://localhost:8080/employee 400 (Bad Request)`

`Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.employee.employee.controller.FormController.employeeSubmit(com.employee.employee.models.Employees,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException: [Field error in object 'employees' on field 'image': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@1cba99d1]; codes [typeMismatch.employees.image,typeMismatch.image,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employees.image,image]; arguments []; default message [image]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]] ]`